# Calculating $\dfrac{d^{m-1}}{ds^{m-1}} \Big(\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Big)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, riemann-zeta

Eq. 1.4 in [Levinson's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69902273) states $$\dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!} \dfrac{d^{m-1}}{ds^{m-1}} \Big(\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Big) = \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^m} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)^m} - \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)^m}.$$ By Eq. 2.12.7 in Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*, $$\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = b - \dfrac{1}{(s-1)} -\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\Gamma'(\frac12 s +1)}{\Gamma(\frac12 s +1)} + \sum_{\rho} \Big( \dfrac{1}{s-\rho} + \dfrac{1}{\rho} \Big).$$ And at page 235 of Whittaker & Watson's book *A Course of Modern Analysis*, we see $$\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2} \log \Gamma(z+1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(z+n)^2}.$$ I calculated for many times and still I get a different series than $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)^m}$ stated in Levinson's paper. For example, for $m=3$ I got $$\dfrac{(-1)^3}{3!} \dfrac{d^2}{ds^2} \Big( -\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\Gamma'(\frac12 s +1)}{\Gamma(\frac12 s +1)} \Big) = \dfrac{(-1)^3}{3!} \dfrac{1}{2^3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{(\frac12 s +n)^3},$$ which differs by a factor of $2$, and also $n$ starts from $1$ not $0$. Is the paper wrong or me?

Comment: Why downvote??? maybe drop a comment to improve my question!

Comment: $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ has a Hadamard product representation in terms of $\rho, 2n$ though you need some Weierstrass factors but those are just order $1$ since $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is order $1$; if you take the logarithmic derivative you get first  $\frac{1}{s-1}+\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)=C+\sum (1/(s+2n)-1/2n)+\sum (1/(s-\rho)-1/\rho)$ and then taking second or higher derivatives everything but the corresponding simple fractions goes away

Comment: @Conrad, in the paper $n$ starts at $0$, this is one problem; the other problem is that both formulas in Titchmarsh and W&W are correct so maybe the formula in paper is wrong which is highly unlikely since it is published.

Comment: the starting at zero is probably a typo but otherwise formula is correct

Comment: @Conrad, Even ignoring that, for a simple m=3 there is an extra factor... let me recalculate maybe I made a mistake. Confusion comes because of s/2 instead of s.

Comment: the formula comes just from general principles and is true for all entire functions of order $1$ (in other words if $w_n$ are the zeroes of an entire function of order $1$ one has $f'/f(s)=C+\sum(1/(s-w_n)-1/w_n)$ since $\sum 1/w_n^2$ converges absolutely by general theory (or just noting that the number of $|w_n| \le R$ is $O(R^{1+\epsilon}$; then differentiating term by term gives the formula for the successive derivatives of $f'/f$